# Optimal way to search and replace non-numeral data in a big dataframe

Tags: regex, pandas, python-2.7, alphanumeric

I have a big dataframe with over 12 million rows and one of the columns `timelogs` is a mix of alphanumeric and some special characters. I want to remove all the non-numeral characters from `timelogs` before finally converting that column to datetime by performing `pd.to_datetime(df['timestr'])`. I am performing below operation to remove non-numeral characters and it is taking **30-45 mins.** to perform this operation:

```
df.loc[:, 'timestr'] = df['timelogs'].str.replace('([^0-9]+)', '')
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a faster way?

Comment: `df['timelogs'].apply(lambda x: "".join([c for c in x if c.isdigit()]))`?

Comment: @Zero thx will try it but I read somewhere that for pd.to_datetime to not be slow ensure that the format of supplied string/object is uniform. Otherwise it would be too slow.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why do you think lambda would be faster which is essentially a for loop on >12 million rows.

Comment: @Zero Format is not uniform. For example, some logs have only dates, some have dates and time until minutes, others have date and time until seconds. Also without removing non-numeral characters the dates and times could be separated by different characters; so making format different for each of them.

Comment: 1) Have you tested? 2) What makes you think 25 min is too long for 12M rows?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew (1) I will test it as soon as script reaches the stage of having the dataset, (2) iterating 12M rows in ~30mins is long compared to all other operations I am performing on this `df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`translate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.translate.html) with the following translation table:

```
import string
tt = str.maketrans('', '', string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.whitespace)
```

In my test with a series of 100K alphanumeric strings of length 20 this is about 35 % faster than `replace`.

```
x = np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits), [100_000, 20])
s = pd.Series([''.join(x[i]) for i in range(len(x))])

    0        4r7xNfZyvbZjcg6sb9UY
    1        GqQywPb0JCHcvRXWV8yV
    2        8zyOOyC38qoztCZzshoP
    3        iemM6xXIkf6xaoAPFlSr
    4        uJYCeuftjkDQSwNchYU2
                     ...
    99995    ugH4TvzuEvB5f2Cp5Mlt
    99996    SYXsz75l9qApOHJDoIF9
    99997    34Xyz45JDx1HFojpWTL2
    99998    BSyhzbx57H9V237PZgqp
    99999    q9Bo9lwKw6O7y7G9G5aQ
    Length: 100000, dtype: object
```

---

```
%timeit s.apply(lambda x: "".join([c for c in x if c.isdigit()]))
#174 ms ± 960 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit s.str.replace('([^0-9]+)', '')
#136 ms ± 443 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit s.str.translate(tt)
#88.5 ms ± 348 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The longer the strings the better is `translate` in relation to `replace`:

[image]